# Can't use VSCode integrated terminal while on Team Viewer

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, command-line, remote-desktop

My development team recently rented a Mac machine through [MacInCloud](https://www.macincloud.com/).

I've prepared my development environment in this machine, but it seems like Visual Studio Code does not register certain keystrokes correctly like ENTER and BACKSPACE from my local machine (I'm using linux). Ex. When I open the terminal and I enter BACKSPACE for deleting a character an 'a' in inserted, the same goes for the ENTER key.

[image]

Is there a hidden setting in team viewer for fixing this behavior or a general way to bedbug keyboard mapping or shortcut functions when they fail to work as expected?

Comment: have you checked the input settings on the remote machine? what is the keyboard layout? Tried on-screen-keyboard from the the remote OS? does it only happen with vscde or in other programs?

Comment: Looks like this is a common error: https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/49394/keyboard-mapping-issues

Comment: Pretty much happens in all applications, I tried on my windows laptop and the error is gone, seems like a Linux only error.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked about on-screen kb from the remote OS. sounds like this particular client(TW) does not like linux for some reason... maybe the easiest solution would be to try another remote connection software (if that's an option...)

Comment: Any (free) recommendations?

Comment: heard chrome has some remote connection option, maybe you wanna give that a try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a known bug with Team Viewer's Keyboard mapping on Linux, read more [here](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/49394/keyboard-mapping-issues). This is a Team Viewer error only and can be fixed by using another Remote Access software, I am using [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/) (as suggested by [user206904](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/410160/user206904)) though performance is not great.